# Is it accepted to suggest someone a "last resort method", when it comes to love matters?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange post: [How to ask cashier out for date](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/how-to-ask-cashier-out-for-date/11129#11129)

See my answer. As per OP's question, he looks like he's not going back. We've all been there. Our friends say no, but love takes away all rational thought.

While, yes, in a perfect world we'd be able to control our emotions, this is often not the case and what could come out from OP's situation is a silly embarassment that he'll laugh at in the years to come.

**Or, well, a search warrant, depending on if he has issues or not, but let's not talk about it and assume this is a love-striken, normal dude.**

As such, I provided the asker with a framework on what he could specifically do to avoid a direct hit from the girl he's trying to get with, in the same time acknowledging the pain points and the possible pitfalls.

This might seem as "evil", but is it doing anyone any good, me, the OP or anyone that'll get to see the question and answer to ignore the fact that, as noted in my opening, when it comes to love, people often don't back down?

My idea is that of minimizing damages, for both parties.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but Jonathan seems to be asking if answering a question with a purposefully sub-par suggestion is okay when the OP seems as though they will not try what you believe to be the ideal answer.

Comment: or in other words - *"Is it okay to compromise your answer in order to achieve a suggestion that the OP might actually listen to."*

Comment: @Jesse Interesting premise. I'm not sure I could provide a good, in SE/IPS terms, answer and still "dumb it down"

Comment: *"Jonathan seems to be asking if answering a question with a purposefully sub-par suggestion is okay when the OP seems as though they will not try what you believe to be the ideal answer. "* _ Not exactly so simple, I don't think he's deliberately writing a mediocre answer @Jesse: given that it seems to @ Jonathan Guerin that OP has decided to to approach the girl, he gave OP the sort of 'last resort' advice that basically assumes his mind is made up on this line of action, and attempts to guide him towards some reasonable outcome based on that premise.

Comment: @EnglishStudent if his "last resort" was the ideal answer, then what was his "first attempt"? By ideal answer I mean the answer OP would have liked to give if they knew the questioner had not already made up their mind

Comment: *"By ideal answer I mean the answer OP would have liked to give if they knew the questioner had not already made up their mind "* __  I was thjnking "objectively ideal interpersonal answer to the question if OP has an open mind", as in, the much upvoted and accepted answer on that page. Thanks for clarifying your meaning @Jesse.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it accepted to suggest someone a “last resort method”, when it comes to love matters?

Sure, no-one is forbidding it. Do note that if people find your advice unuseful, they are free to downvote it. If someone else thinks it shouldn't be done at all, they can write their own answer explaining how to 'minimize danger' even further.

Just like lying, we can't really forbid you from giving advice on 'how to do it anyway'. Just make sure your answer points out what the damage is going to be, so an asker doesn't take it for granted as 'here's how I can safely do it'.

Comment: I understand. It seems this Stack Exchange isn't for me, as with most "pseudo" stack exchanges, people do value "positive" answers over realistic ones. That guy's going to be burned off, unless she also likes him.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why your answer seems to set on assuming they will act on these feelings.

The OP accepted the answer that said "do nothing" and warned against the alternative method you mentioned (trying to meet her after work).

I don't think it's because you included a "last resort method" that the answer was poorly received.  I think it's because it doesn't seem like a good answer in general.  It doesn't add much new to the discussion; basically all of this is suggested in other answers.  It also seems pretty rant-based.

Comment: Understood. Makes sense.